# MyBatis doesn't understand sql line breaks

Tags: sql, mybatis

For example, when in `import.sql` I write

```
CREATE TABLE user ( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50), birthday DATE);
```

on one line, it's okay, but if I would write like this

```
CREATE TABLE user 
(
    id       INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name     VARCHAR(50),
    birthday DATE
);
```

it will cause an error:

> Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE USER ( [*]"; expected  identifier"; SQL statement: CREATE TABLE user ( [42001-193]

How can I fix this?